# How to use both onclick and target="_blank"

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Code is as following:

```
    <p class="downloadBoks" onclick="location.href='Prosjektplan.pdf'">Prosjektbeskrivelse</p>
```

Works fine like this, but it opens the file in the same window. I want to apply the target="_blank". But after some googleing I still can't figure it out.

Comment: target="_blank" is for <a> tags not <p>

Comment: The   location.href=  was just the thing i was looking for

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Instead use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open):

The syntax is:

```
window.open(strUrl, strWindowName[, strWindowFeatures]);
```

Your code should have:

```
window.open('Prosjektplan.pdf');
```

Your code should be:

```
<p class="downloadBoks"
   onclick="window.open('Prosjektplan.pdf')">Prosjektbeskrivelse</p>
```

Comment: Not entirely true. The `target` attrib is no longer deprecated. Ref: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html; and `a` is any day preferable over using a `p` to link to a resource using javascript.

Comment: Oh yeah... The target attribute on the a element was deprecated in a previous version of HTML, but is no longer deprecated, as it useful in Web applications, particularly in combination with the iframe element.

Comment: Doesn't work on mobile, and gets blocked. This is much worse than leaving the target blank to work as usual and listening for the event.

Comment: do not forget to add return=false in order to stay in the same URL in the main window (event prevent default) => 

onclick="window.open('Prosjektplan.pdf');return false;"

Comment: @eosphere Nopes! Not in case of `<p>`. What's the default event on paragraph that you're trying to prevent? 

Comment: @Praveen : in fact in my case it was a <button> and not a <p> !

Comment: @eosphere Then yes.

Answer (score 43):

```
onclick="window.open('your_html', '_blank')"
```

Comment: '_blank' is useless in that context

Answer (score 8):

Just use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open):

```
window.open('Prosjektplan.pdf')
```

Anyway, what guys are saying on comments is true. You better use `<a target="_blank">` instead of click events.

Answer (score 5):

you can use

```
        <p><a href="/link/to/url" target="_blank"><button id="btn_id">Present Name </button></a></p>
```

Comment: Yes. This is the genius answer.

Answer (score 0):

The window.open method is prone to cause popup blockers to complain

A better approach is:

Put a form in the webpage with an id

`<form action="theUrlToGoTo" method="post" target="yourTarget"  id="yourFormName">
</form>`

Then use:

```
function openYourRequiredPage() {
var theForm = document.getElementById("yourFormName");
theForm.submit();
```

}

and

`onclick="Javascript: openYourRequiredPage()"`

You can use

`method="post"`

or

`method="get"`

As you wish

Comment: This does not work either. It gets detected as a popup and blocked in all major browsers

Comment: Make sure that the tab to open is https

Answer (score 0):

All these solutions don't work properly to fix  the issue you have to put your string in a variable and wrap it all up in an iframe like this:

```
   const newWindow = window.open();
  newWindow.document.write(`
    <html>
      <body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden;">
        <iframe
          src="${pdfUrl}"
          title="PDF Viewer"
          style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; border: none;"
        ></iframe>
      </body>
    </html>
  `);
};
```