# Rails link_to and onClick with target=_blank does not work together

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

I believe this should have quite an easy solution but I am not used to work with JavaScript.

I wanted to add the event handler to Google Analytics and did so by using their suggestion code:

```
<script>
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {'hitCallback':
     function () {
     document.location = url;
     }
   });
}
</script>
```

with each link link this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" onClick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">Example.com</a>
```

This works fine, Analytics-wise, but I have lost the possibility to open the link in a new window. I assume the JavaScript overrides that in some way, so I how do I make sure I can still use HTML options like `target=_blank` together with the `onClick`? I really rather not want to handle opening new windows in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to use `window.open()`

```
<script>
  var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {'hitCallback':
     function () {
         window.open(url);
      }
      });
    }
</script>
```

Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588708/how-to-use-both-onclick-and-target-blank)

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem. However, it is being solved in means of JavaScript which could complicate things further on. I still would like a non-javascript solution to this problem, if there is none I will award you the "solution".