# html href link to a new page under form tag

Tags: html, forms, hyperlink, target

I'm creating a email template for validation email for user sign-up. Below is the html code:

```
<form>
    <input style="width: 300px; padding: 20px; cursor: pointer; font-weight: bold; background: #141452; color: #ffffff; border-radius: 10px;font-size: 150%;" type="button" 
           value="Verify my email address" onclick="window.location.href='https://www.google.com/'"/>
    </form>
```

I want to open the link in a new tab instead. Does anyone know how to incorporate "Target" in this code block?

Thanks!

Comment: This should help;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588708/how-to-use-both-onclick-and-target-blank

Comment: You can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141910/javascript-location-href-to-open-in-new-window-tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');
```