# javascript onclick into a new window

Tags: javascript, onclick

Here is my code

```
 <button style ="background-color:Blue ; color:white" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com'">google</button>
```

And it works just fine, nice looking button that opens the website.  But I need it to open in another window, not the same one.  Obviously this is using javascript.  But for some reason I can't seem to figure this out.  It seems like such a simple thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use both onclick and target="\_blank"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588708/how-to-use-both-onclick-and-target-blank)

Answer (score 3):

Use `window.open()` instead of `window.location.href`:

```
<button style ="background-color:Blue ; color:white" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com')">google</button>
```

For more info about `window.open()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `window.open()` with JavaScript - find out more here >  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

```
<button style ="background-color:Blue ; color:white" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com')">google</button>
```

FYI if you were using a `a` tag you can use `target="_blank"` :) which in this situtation fits your solution more

```
<a style="background-color:Blue; color:white;" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google></a>
```

Comment: That solves my issue.  Thanks for the quick response.