# html/css/javascript: how do i open a href in another tab if it is onclick

Tags: javascript, html

```
<td onclick="window.location.href='https:/www.geogebra.org/calculator';"><img src="Geogebra.png" alt="Geogebra Icon" width="30" height="30"></td>
```

how do i open a new tab if i click on it?

i've tried this: `<td onclick="window.location.href='https:/www.geogebra.org/calculator'target='_blank';"><img  src="Geogebra.png" alt="Geogebra Icon" width="30" height="30"></td>`
but it didnt work...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript onclick into a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393499/javascript-onclick-into-a-new-window)

Comment: ie wrap it in window.open like this: `<td onclick="window.open('https:/www.geogebra.org/calculator');"><img  src="Geogebra.png" alt="Geogebra Icon" width="30" height="30"></td> `

Comment: Why don't you just put an `<a>` in the `<td>`?